# ThemeResource color doesn't follow app's theme UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, winui

I have a flyout that I created programmatically for my UWP app and I applied the `SystemFillColorCautionBackgroundBrush` background color from the WinUI gallery to it:

```
//create a flyout
var flyout = new Flyout();

//create a textblock
var textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text =
    "Prima di salvare l'allegato è necessario contrassegnare la comunicazione come letta sul server. Confermi?";
textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords;
textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 12);

var flyoutPresenterStyle = new Style(typeof(FlyoutPresenter));

flyoutPresenterStyle.Setters.Add(
    new Setter(
        FlyoutPresenter.BackgroundProperty,
        (Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush)
            Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorCautionBackgroundBrush"]
    )
);

//make the flyout wrap the text vertically
flyoutPresenterStyle.Setters.Add(
    new Setter(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode.Disabled)
);
flyoutPresenterStyle.Setters.Add(
    new Setter(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled)
);

//make the flyoutPresenterStyle based on the default one
flyoutPresenterStyle.BasedOn = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["DefaultFlyoutPresenterStyle"];

flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle = flyoutPresenterStyle;

//create a button
var button = new Button();
button.Content = "Leggi e apri";
```

The problem is that the theme of the background color I chose doesn't change based on my App's requested theme:
[image]

How can I set the theme of that flyout background color?

**Update 1**:
Also, I observed that on Windows 11 Version 22H2 this issue isn't present. This only happens on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use [ThemeResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension#remarks) in xaml, it can re-evaluate when the theme changes, the code is as follows.

```
<Button Content="Empty cart">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemFillColorCautionBackgroundBrush}"/>
                </Style>
            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is some text in a flyout."/>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

## Edit 2023/5/3

If you want to access it from the code, you can create a new custom Flyout style, and use it from the code. For test, I define the style in App.xaml.cs. You can refer to the following code.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <controls:XamlControlsResources>
        <controls:XamlControlsResources.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other app resources here -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style x:Name="NewflyoutStyle" TargetType="FlyoutPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultFlyoutPresenterStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemFillColorCautionBackgroundBrush}" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </controls:XamlControlsResources.MergedDictionaries>
    </controls:XamlControlsResources>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
var flyoutPresenterStyle = new Style(typeof(FlyoutPresenter));

//flyoutPresenterStyle.Setters.Add(
//    new Setter(
//        FlyoutPresenter.BackgroundProperty,
//        (Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush)
//            Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorCautionBackgroundBrush"]
//    )
//);

//make the flyout wrap the text vertically
flyoutPresenterStyle.Setters.Add(
    new Setter(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode.Disabled)
);
flyoutPresenterStyle.Setters.Add(
    new Setter(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled)
);

//make the flyoutPresenterStyle based on the custom one
flyoutPresenterStyle.BasedOn = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["NewflyoutStyle"];

flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle = flyoutPresenterStyle;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to define the flyout in XAML and then access/display it from the code? I need to do this because the code executed when clicking the button is dynamic and also the displayed text is.

Comment: Also, I observed that this issue with the background color theme on Windows 11 Version 22H2 isn't present. This only happens on Windows 10. Is this a recognized issue?

Comment: I edited the answer, you can refer to it.